# Induction surface started making a barely noticeable high-pitch whining noise, even when it is not in use, is this dangerous?

Tags: equipment, induction

We have been using a 4-slot Amica induction surface for 4 years now, and it started making a barely noticeable high-pitch whining noise, even when it is not in use. Is this dangerous? Can aging induction surfaces pose a danger of electrocution, fire or something else?

Comment: Whining noises from electrical equipment often mean an issue with a transformer. A thingie that changes a low voltage to a high one, or vice-versa. I would say that to be on the safe side call the manufacturer or a certified repair specialist. It **might** be fine, but why chance an electrical fire or other issue?

Comment: Yes, we are already waiting for a specialist, but I also wanted a community opinion on this one.

Comment: duplicate?  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12688/induction-unit-makes-buzzing-sound

Comment: @jim afair, I checked that question, but it refers to an oven during cooking. We  got one while it wasn't cooking.

Answer (score 2):

Glad you are getting this checked out.

As Steve mentioned, it sounds like the power supply or the supporting electronics for the hob is starting to fail. To be on the safe side, I would isolate the power to it if at all possible (UK hobs are required to have a wall mounted isolation switch).

Certified electrical appliances are designed to "Fail safe” so the risk of fires etc. is small, but your hob is sending you a clear warning sign that it is not very well and should be turned off. Depending on the nature of the fault, this may eventually result in absolutely nothing at all (apart from mild irritation), a totally dead hob, a small bang, or indeed a big bang. The greatest risk you are probably taking is that your insurance company will not cover you should something adverse happen and they prove you continued using the device despite being aware of it malfunctioning.

Comment: We serviced it, parts were replaced (I think the transformer), but my wife says she can still hear the hum, so we just keep it unpowered when not in use, as you have suggested (luckily, there is a separate fuse for the oven itself).

Comment: If the engineer replaced some parts, that suggests he was not happy with their condition/performance. Does isolating the hob get rid of the hum? Depending on how far you want to take this, while I don't think there is any risk to either of you, having to pull the fuse to ensure the peace of mind of your partner, is IMO, not ideal.

Comment: I'm considering replacing the whole unit.